# Using an svg file with a Script tag from within svg

Tags: svg, scripting

So the devil is in the details in this question.

I want to create some svg components with encapsulated behaviour (and therefore I want to include a script tag inside the external svg file(s)).  Now, this works fine from HTML5 when you include via object or embed, etc.  But I want to reference these svg files from within an svg tag (inside an svg element).

So, from within svg, the only ways I know of to include an svg file (via xlink:href) is with either an image tag or a use tag.  Neither, however, will accept a script tag in their content model, which I *assume* is why the script tags are not being interpreted (and I'm pretty sure they are not being interpreted).  I am escaping the scripts in CData format inside the svgs, so I don't think it is a parsing problem.

Here is a brief example of what I mean.

The Html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id"top">
      <svg id="map" viewBox = "0 0 500 500" version = "1.1" width="250" height="250"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <image x="0" y="110" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="svg/obj/example.svg" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And svg/obj/example.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 500" version = "1.1" width="250" height="250"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
    function circle_click(evt) {
      var circle = evt.target;
      var currentRadius = circle.getAttribute("r");
      if (currentRadius == 100)
        circle.setAttribute("r", currentRadius*2);
      else
        circle.setAttribute("r", currentRadius*0.5);
    }
  ]]> </script>

  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" onclick="circle_click(evt)" onactivate="circle_click(evt)" mouseover="circle_click()"/>

</svg>
```

To eliminate the likelihood of parsing errors, I cut and paste the above script from a W3C example (iir).  I've tried many variations on this theme, but can't seem to get it working.  The specifics are sufficiently conflated that searching just brings up different use cases.  Hopefully someone here can take me out of my misery ;).

Comment: "Now, this works fine from HTML5 when you include via object or embed, etc." and would likely not work at all when included via an image tag, And hence the same issue with SVG. I am not sure but I believe it would be treated no differently than an image in HTML and scripts would not work.

Comment: Yeah, for sure the script tags are ignored when the file is included via an SVG <image/> or <use/> tag.  The question is, how to include an svg file from within an svg in-line tag (or another svg file) such that its script tag *is* read and interpreted.